# How to set a background image from array of objects in Bootstrap carousel jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have array of items, and every item(object) has property background where I store a url to image.This is my array
[image: console]

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
        <!-- Inner -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>
        <!-- Controlls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and this is script from jQuery plugin:

```
$(items).each(function(index){
                $('.carousel-inner', self).append('<div class="item"><div class="container"><div class="carousel-caption">' + this.tournamentName + ' / ' + this.matchStatusName + '</div>');
                $('.carousel-inner div.item.active').css('background', 'url(' + this.background + ')');
                $('.carousel-indicators', self).append('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'+index+'"></li>');
                $('.carousel-indicators li:first, .carousel-inner div.item:first', self).addClass('active');
                $(self).carousel();
            });
```

I tried to set background `$('.carousel-inner .item.active').css('background', 'url(' + this.background + ')');` and also `$('.carousel-inner div.item.active').css('background', 'url(' + this.background + ')');`but this won't work, it shows only first item with that image and stays that way until reach it to the end of slides.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `$('.carousel-inner div.item.active')` , here you are trying to select the div with class active, But your div doesn't have active class yet.

Replace your this line of code

```
$('.carousel-inner div.item.active').css('background', 'url(' + this.background + ')');
```

With

```
$('.carousel-inner div.item:eq('+index+')').css('background', 'url(' + this.background + ')');
```

Comment: I understand but i didn't know how to reach active div. Thank you very much  it works perfect!

Comment: No problem, :) You can accept this answer if at all this solution solved your problem .